# Optaplanner: customize inclusion on indictment list

Tags: java, optaplanner

**tl;dr** In the indictment list, is there a way to include only (for example) object `A` from a `BiConstraintStream<A, B>`? And as an aside from that question, is it possible to set references to `PlanningEntity`s on a `ProblemFact` during the construction of a `PlanningSolution`, so we can quickly reference them later during constraint calculation?

---

Full question:

I currently have a constraint that looks roughly as follows:

```
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Participation.class)
                .groupBy(Participation::getStudent, toList())
                .filter((student, participations) -> student.getMinEnrollments() != null)
                .penalize("Not enough hours enrolled",
                        HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                        (student, participationList) -> student.getMinEnrollments() - participationList.stream().filter(Participation::getEnrolled).count();
                );
```

This gives me exactly the penalty I want, in my case a penalty for each student that does not have enough enrollments.

When, after solving, I look at the indictment list, I see something like

```
        -12soft: justification (STUDENT_1) has 1 matches:
            -12soft: constraint (Not enough hours enrolled)
        -12soft: justification ([List, Of, Participation, Objects, ...]) has 1 matches:
            -12soft: constraint (Not enough hours enrolled)
        -8soft: justification (STUDENT_2) has 1 matches:
            -8soft: constraint (Not enough hours enrolled)
        ...
```

This suggests to me (and some experimentation seems to confirm this) that every part of a (Uni, Bi, Tri, Quad)ConstraintStream ends up in the indictment list, which I guess makes sense in a way.

In my use case (and since I want to make use of the indictment list), for this constraint I would like only the student to show up in this list, and not the list of participations.

One thing I have tried is creating a BiConstraintStream<Student, Integer> where "Integer" is the penalty I want to set, and end with something like

```
.penalize("Not enough hours enrolled",
                HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                (student, penalty) -> penalty
        );
```

This works in theory (with the correct result), but I still get the raw numbers as a part of my indictment list.

A final thing I have tried is that during the construction of my PlanningSolution, I set a list of `Participation` objects (my `PlanningEntity`s) on my `Student` objects which are ProblemFacts.
This would then enable me to do as follows:

```
        return constraintFactory
                .forEach(Student.class)
                .filter(student -> student.getMinEnrollments() != null)
                .penalize("Not enough hours enrolledv2",
                        HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                        (student) -> student.getMinEnrollments() - student.getParticipations().filter(Participation::getEnrolled).count();
                );
```

I guess this would be more efficient anyway, since I am precomputing the relation between Participations and Students at initialization time instead of during every penalty calculation (and Students are not a PlanningVariable on Participations, so there is no problem there).

However, this does then not work since at the point of constraint calculation the student.getParticipations() objects no longer correspond to the PlanningEntities I constructed originally (I guess Optaplanner makes some clone of these objects which means references cannot be used this way?)

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Also see the tl;dr above.

Comment: No API for that at the moment. Maybe an RFE we want to add? I guess you could translate the indictement list after you get it, but it would put the translating code far away from the constraint code...

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet yeah, that was my final option, looking at the indictment list after the fact. But indeed not what I'd like to do due to the reason you mention. Just to be clear, is there also no way to reverse the relationship between planningentity and problem fact? So that you could forEach over a problemfact and get the related planningentities? Since that would also solve my problem in this case

Comment: Planning facts must not reference entities - entities change, facts do not. But nothing prevents you from referencing facts from entities, and doing `forEach(Fact.class).join(Entity.class, equal(Function.identity(), Entity::getFact))`.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický Yeah, I should have been more clear in my last comment, I was trying to reverse the relationship without joining to the `Entity` from in my constraint, since I was trying to prevent the Entity (list) from ending up in my indictment list. But I think the answer is clear that that's (currently) not possible, so I'll have to make do for now.